# io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException: Failed to parse resource at

Tags: maven, cucumber, junit-runner

I am trying to build a framework using io.cucumber but gives me an error which mentions in the title

**TestRunner File**

```
package Test_Runner;


import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;



@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome = true,
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        plugin = { "pretty","html:target/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber.json" },
        glue = "Test_Runner/Steps",
        dryRun = true)
public class TestRunner {
}
```

When I am running with an older version of cucumber dependency it's not giving error.

The error shows when I run is as below

```
io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException: Failed to parse resource at: file:///G:/Testing/Projects/RanajiAgro/src/test/resources/features/Login.feature

    at io.cucumber.core.gherkin.vintage.GherkinVintageFeatureParser.parseGherkin5(GherkinVintageFeatureParser.java:40)
```

Comment: it's solved. I added the wrong dependency just change  io.cucumber » cucumber-gherkin instead of io.cucumber » gherkin

Comment: You should remove that dependency. It's transitive so your tooling should download it automatically. Assuming you don't download them by hand.

Comment: The error is telling you it cannot parse the **feature** file. Can you [edit] your question to include Login.feature?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the specified feature file (entire file) for proper gherkin format.
Even a blank space between **Scenario** and **:** can cause this issue as well

Usual Typo Mistakes causing the error

1. Scenario(blank Space): and Scenario Outline(blank space):
2. Instead of Examples, most use Example
3. |Name||password|| - unwanted || for parameters

Answer (score 0):

GO to the problematic gherkin feature file and do the below 'Pretty format'
For Intellij press ->  Ctrl + Alt + L
For Eclipse press ->  Ctrl + Shift + F

Answer (score 0):

One simple space can cause the problem.

i had :

Feature : my feature

adding the space after Feature caused the problem;

so i did :

Feature: my feature